# Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll crashes app WeatherLink 6.0.5

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio

The error "Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll" is generated when the app WeatherLink 6.0.5 crashes.

The event log reports:

Faulting application name: WeatherLink 6.0.5.exe, version: 6.0.5.0, time stamp: 0x5b638b21
Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524f7ce6
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000a46a9
Faulting process id: 0xb80
Faulting application start time: 0x01d723c977fefac0
Faulting application path: C:\WeatherLink\WeatherLink 6.0.5.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120.dll
Report Id: 669196e7-c960-4b24-bb84-77414424aa21
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

The PC is running 32 bit  Windows 10 Pro Version 20H2 build 19042.906  4GB RAM  Intel Atom D525 @1.8GHz  System normally reports 1.5GB RAM in use.  WeatherLink using 5.3MB normally.

I reinstalled WeatherLink and assured all Windows updates and optional updates installed.  No change.

I then wiped the PC and installed Windows again and then WeatherLink.  System seemed to work fine for some time but has now started failing again.  It normally happens overnight .  AV software is Microsoft Defender. The PC is connected to a 1500VA UPS and APC software is installed on the PC to manage the UPS. No other applications have been installed.

The app can be restarted and sometimes runs for a few days.

There are sometimes issues writing to files in the C:\WeatherLink folder which is the default install location for the app.  App reports unable to write.  The application hangs at that point but does not close and generate an error. The event does not appear in any log.  The logged on user has Full Control of the folder and files.

Software vendor support reports "This error is with the "Visual C++, in Visual Studio" that we rely on."  Suggests contacting a computer technician.

The system has Visual C++ 2008,2013 and 2015 Redistributable installed and the installs have been repaired following the complete Windows reinstall.

Vendor support indicates they have no connection to error and that it is solely Visual C++.

I have seen a number of posts reporting that MSVCR120.dll is missing and creating issues but not the same issue.

The application ran under Windows 7 for many years without issue.  Vendor support says it runs under Windows 10

UPDATE

Today the system threw error “Cannot write to C:\weatherlink\download.log”  The app remained open and clearing the error popup allowed the screen to refresh with latest data.  The user is local admin and has full control of the Weatherlink folder and all files.

No error listed in Event Log for that event.

I had uninstalled Visual C++ 2008 and 2015 as suggested by @RAMHOUND but while looking for anything related  to the write error above,[image: Event Log entry] I find Visual C++ 2015 has installed today.  Could this be related to Windows Defender update?  Definitions updated earlier today.

Around the same time, there is activity in System Log around Skype but do not see any install change.  Also Microsoft Edge reports a change on 9 Apr 2021.

No recent events in the Setup Log.

Did a repair of Visual C++ 2013, shutdown and restarted.

A day later (11 Apr 2021) the same error is recorded and app has crashed.  No change in installed apps.

April 12 2021-

Clean Win 10 install and latest updates. Tried to install latest version but needed earlier.  Tried 6.0.3 which was most recent that was not an upgrade but it wants Visual C++ 2008.  Stopped install. Copied entire folder from system before wipe and installed update assuming whatever upgrade needed would be there.  That allowed install.  Only Visual C++ 2013 is installed.

Will leave running for a few days before installing APC PowerChute Personal.

Comment: Latest news I see about Weather Link is from 2018. So you may need to check if it is compliant for the newest version of Windows 10

Comment: "The system has Visual C++ 2008,2013 and 2015" - The only version the application requires is the `Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable`.  My suggestion is to uninstall all versions and only install the required version.   "App reports unable to write." - Please provide an adequate information required to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound   Will grab the write error message next time it happens.

Comment: @John  The vendor reports it is compliant

Comment: You said you reinstalled Windows and did all the updates, so I am not sure why this error would occur. I will look around a bit.

Comment: @john The new Windows install in January was a clean install.  Installed Windows latest build and updated.  Installed WeatherLink and then updated as my original purchase was an older version.  Installed the APC software as the PC manages the attached UPS.  No other software installed.  Just uninstalling Visual C++ 2008 and 2015 as suggested by Ramhound

Comment: "Could this be related to Windows Defender update? Definitions updated earlier today." - You probably have third-party software that requires VC++ 2015.  What are the permissions of `C:\weatherlink\download.log`?

Comment: @Ramhound The user is local admin and has full control of the Weatherlink folder and all files.  Permission for "Download.log" is full control

Comment: I want screenshots, because the application cannot write to the log, which means it cannot be used to diagnose the problem which means until that changes your problem cannot be diagnosed

Comment: @Ramhound  What screenshot would you like?  The can't write error, while annoying, is not the most critical issue.  The app remains open.  That log records the download of data from the weather station and any uploads to Davis, Wunderground  and another government site. The "Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll" error crashes the app.  The can't write error happens once in a  while, the MSVCR120.dll error sometimes multiple times a day

Comment: @Ramhound  The log does contain errors resulting from attempts to upload to an FTP server that is no longer used.  However, the app keeps running and other uploads report successful.   I have reported more details to vendor support but do not expect more as they say it is simply a Visual C++ issue, not their software

Comment: If there software is creating a software exception within the Visual C++ 2013 library, then that is there problem to fix, it's unclear if the software is functional or functional but has numerous crashes due to being unsupported.

Comment: Going to try a couple of things.  Another full wipe and reinstall  of PC and monitor install of the two apps to see what is installing Visual C++.  Also installing app on an Intel Compute Stick.  Can't imagine this is a hardware issue, but if it fails on both, it will confirm software